# How to display key values in toolbar which is on keyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am developing one application. In that I have toolbar on keyboard. But I want that when I press keys, the key values should be displayed in toolbar textfield. 
So if anyone knows kindly reply.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a UITextField to your NIB or view? That is the best way to get a keyboard displayed and enter text. You can then retrieve the text using UITextView's text property.

Comment: No Roger actually I have textField on view but it  hides because of keyboard
so i took toolbar attached to keyboard  so when I enter text, the text should be displayed in that.

Comment: you mean the UITextView is under the keyboard? If so you should scroll the whole view up.